# Check if SQL server service is running

Tags: batch-file

Currently we are facing a problem that effects system stability, our server has SQL server 2012 and for unknown reason its services stop running and that needs someone to restart it manually every single day. I have created a command in batch file to restart SQL server automatically and it works fine, however, I am looking for better command that can check if SQL server stop, just restart it, if running, just ignore. How can I do that command that ?

```
@ECHO OFF
NET START MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this. pause is optional. Don't use it if this goes in a scheduled task! In that case you wouldn't need all the echo statements either. Of course you will need to run this with administrative privileges to start the service. I added a check for that.

```
@echo off
set "Service=MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS"
rem Make sure service exists
sc query %Service% | (findstr "does not exist" && goto :Done)

for /f "tokens=1,2,3,4" %%A in ('sc query %Service%') do (
   if /I %%A == STATE (
      if /i not %%D == RUNNING (
         echo(%Service% STATE is %%D.  It should be RUNNING.
         rem openfiles requires admin
         openfiles >nul 2>&1 || (Color E0 & ECHO(You must run with Administrative priveleges to start the service. & goto :Done)
         echo(Starting it now...
         sc start %Service%
         )
      )
   )
:Done
pause
```

Might be a good idea to look through the Windows event log and see if you can determine why the service is stopping, as there is obviously something wrong.

Comment: yeah, need to add a check. Lets say I want to schedule `@ECHO OFF
NET START MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS` in task scheduler, does that grantee that SQL service will keep running ?

Comment: 1. I don't understand... if you are going to put in scheduled task then you need to get that set up to run with admin privs and after that there is no point in checking that every time it is run. 2. No, putting it in a scheduled task only means that it will run until the next time it stops... which could be immediately or the next day. Best to figure out why it is stopping instead of this band-aid fix.

Comment: Edited my answer to allow any user to run to check status, but put up message that this must be run as admin if it was not.and service needs to be started.

Comment: How to add time to your answer code,, lets say want this code to be executed every 10 minutes, how to do that?

Comment: Use the Task Scheduler. In the 'Advanced' section of triggers you can control repeated execution. Although you still should figure out why the service is stopping.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sc` to query the status:

```
sc query MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS | findstr /I /C:STATE | findstr /I /C:RUNNING
If ERRORLEVEL 1 sc start MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
```

But since you have Server 2012, Powershell is another option:

```
$service = Get-Service -Name MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS

If ($service.Status -ine "running") {
   $service | Start-Service
}
```